# How to create a new ngx_connection_t from inside nginx

Tags: c, nginx

I want to create a new connection from inside nginx.

I want to make a copy of the incoming request and create a connection from another server.

I want that if a user triggers a get request which is intended to go to server X, a copy of the request is created and sent to server Y

I am able to create a new connection using ngx_get_connection.

I am presently doing it as 
c = ngx_get_connection(fd, ngx_cycle->log);

I want to know what all values i need to fill in the connection i got and where to fetch them from.

Can i create a request and the pool allocated to the request can be assigned to connection as well or can i fetch it from conf.

Any direction will help.

Comment: if you don't mind, maybe you should clarify your question a little bit. thanks.

Comment: @Sourav I have tried to clarify it a bit more.Please tell if anything else i can do to make it more clear